# How would a group of people on a rogue planet expand their settlement into an empire with minimal resources?

Tags: civilization, survival

The type of rogue planet I am referring to is a terrestrial planet that has been ejected from it's solar system during it forming. The planet has a thin atmosphere and has no star, because of this the planet's oceans have froze in an almost twenty mile deep ice cover. This takes place in the Star wars universe, a group of people were on an exploration mission into the Unknown Regions when the group's hyperdrive malfunctioned and launched them deep into the strange region on the edge of the galaxy. The group of around eighty people had the resources to set up a small base and a few mining equipment but, how would they turn that into a civilization into the center for a powerful empire?

Comment: To be misshapen, it must be smaller than the largest of the asteroids -- which is too small to keep anything we'd normally call an atmosphere...

Comment: I'll discard that Idea then, thank you

Comment: VTC what is here to scientifically deduce - or they have sufficient tech capacities and vison to do so, or they do not or they fail for reasons beyond they control. There are 1000's ways for success and billion ways to fail. What kind of objective clarity, scientifically plausible improvements can we bring here - use nanomachines and portable teleporters with 10ly range and you have all things for success

Comment: This is the Star Wars universe, although it is advanced it is also strangely not. The exploration team would only have one or two air tight domes, one smaller ship capable of carrying a few passengers. The composition of the Unknow Regions would make it hard to even find another planet, they would have to stay close to the planet and any surrounding bodies. They do have equipment capable of extracting resources from the planet they land on but how would they expand outward?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to establish a settlement or how to turn a small settlement on a rogue planet into a powerful empire? These are two very different questions, with the latter being way too broad. Please edit your query to clarify your question and to add all the additional details you mention in the comments. Comments tend to disappear and people do not really pay enough attention to them.

Comment: Well the question about the expansion part is more important, I have the building a settlement part mostly figured out.

Comment: @Asher WB.SE rules do not allow multiple questions in one query. Please [edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/207014/edit) your query to limit it to one question. Please consider that if you want to focus on expansion, the information that you have provided is not sufficient. Empires require people, wealth, and military power. Your query does not allow figuring out how to get those three things. We do not even know how far from other settlements your rogue planet is, what resources are available, and if recruiting is even possible.

Comment: To have an empire you must have victims to conquer. Hard to find rich cities to conquer on a barren planet.

Comment: Of the 80 people how many are women young enough to have children ?  It's going to be a very small likelihood of survival long term, let alone expansion to an Empire (which requires somehow building star ships on a icy rock.  Best solution : fix the hyperdrive or the hyper-radio to get off the ice block.

Comment: @StephenG not very familiar with starwars setting(and do not like it, except jedi) but wasn't clone war exactly about that secluded clone raise factory bringing havoc - so it does not matter how much women do they have, it all matter of tech available

Comment: @MolbOrg Cloning is fine is you happen to have a cloning facility and the required support structures and people.  To start with they (presumably) won't have that and how many women are able to have children is going to be rather critical to even having a viable second generation to work from.

Comment: @StephenG not here to fix all the problems with the q comments or whatever - _advanced technologies_ - it includes a lot really - ai, nanotech, good energy sources, bootstraping databases for most situatuions up to level how much u paid for, etc etc. I can write yes answer to original q using one material technology which always with u for reasons one can't refute(health) and one piece of  database 1 terabyte or petabyte which is just installed by default just in case  as part of self rescue kit, with med kit and other stuff - like equivalent of gps and map on mobile. It does not matter.

Comment: @MolbOrg Well you're more or less saying "magic ship" stocked with mining gear (20 miles deep of ice !), cloning equipment, enough data to enable them to reconstruct an empire from it and all that entails, refining equipment (digging isn't much use if you end up with useless rocks), and so on.  It's an unlikely combination for a single ship (why would a ship have cloning facilities and mining facilities in a universe where robots do the work ?).

Comment: @StephenG you asking me to conduct a crash course on advanced futuristic technologies in comments portions on wb? Not a Clarke tech, no magic, just regular convenient nanotech. recent [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/206965/20315) of mine on the topic is not necessarily a good start, but a start nevertheless. Take look at the original q, it was even worse as there was no ship, nothing, people just pop up on the rogue planet. Bootstrapping is an interesting fundamental problem, which has practical uses, and happens to be knowledgeable on the topic, lol. yes-answer is possible.

Comment: that empire thing which ruins the question or else it would be a fine q

Comment: In addition to the reasons stated for closing this question, [questions about 3rd party and/or commercial worlds are off-topic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7336/40609). Such questions would be better asked at [scifi.se]. [worldbuilding.se]'s focus is to help people create and consistently use the rules and systems of a fictional world of their own creation.

Answer (score 2):

A caveman teleported naked from the sauna would die, sure.  But in this case there was a technical problem with the hyperdrive, which is to say, you spilled your beer in it and this time it shorted out.  You popped out in the middle of nowhere with all the hafnium nuclear isomer used up; worse, the reserve tank ... well, you look in the back and the reserve tank is the one you meant to change but never got around to.  Barely enough fuel to hop 200 AU to the nearest rock.

After a miserable couple weeks of *ample recriminations* and astronomy measurements, you hone in on the planet's largest water ice plume.  (Lucky for you, there's enough radioactivity to keep a subsurface ocean going, which is a very good sign for heavy elements)  The engineer says you could probably improvise with induced plutonium decay and lead shielding, but *(looking at you)* somebody would have to ride outside.

Obviously enough, you land in the cryovolcano, and use a few hundred-gram nuclear mining charges to open it up a bit.  The vaporizing ice clears out most of the fallout in no time, and you have yourself a cozy little mining base.  Just expand your origami graphene enclosure to fit, keeping a little extra density toward the vacuum to prevent accidents.  What a relief not to be sharing a hundred square feet with seven people who are mad at you about something.

Now at this point, your settlement is being warmed by evaporating water vapor from beneath, which is a source of hydrogen and oxygen from your nuclear isomer reactor.  You're still spending power to heat it, though not much by space travel standards.  It would be prudent to get a backup energy source just in case anything (ahem) happens to the reactor.  Besides, you're here to mine, which means, it's time to *drill baby drill*.  Lucky for you, your ship has more space for drill casings than for its crew, and the drill itself is built into the ship and powered off the reactor.  The casings are the newest dynamic model, capable of the same restructuring on the fly as a graphene habitation dome, but faster, over a smaller range of motion.  You can drill down and expand the cryovolcanic vent to get to the ocean pretty quickly.

The ocean isn't just a source of warm water - it's a place to launch mining submersibles that can prospect the depths for nodules.  The water itself may contain interesting impurities.  There are some strange chemical imbalances in the water - let's not call them life forms, since that would massively bloat the claims paperwork - but there are some real opportunities there to spear yourself some complex hydrocarbons.

At this point, it's almost easy to forget you're still marooned until you collect enough 178m2 or other nuclear fuel to try another jump.  It would be just another mining mission, except ... the cook sabotaged the beer recycler.  Cruel man.

Comment: You basically wrote that part of my story for me, this was very interesting. I will use some of these concepts I just couldn't figure out how to explain this. There are a few problems but that's not that big of a deal, can I use this with some changes and not as many metaphors to explain the civilization.?

Comment: As far as I recall Stack Exchange is free licensed anyway, but sure, by all means go ahead!  If I actually wrote a percent of what I like to daydream about, maybe I'd be more of a hoarder...  Plus, I see you've been busted for creativity without a license, so if you don't use it, it is all wasted anyway.

Comment: chemical imbalances - that a good one, lol

Answer (score 1):

They would die.

If they are "suddenly teleported", they would not have the tools with them to survive. They would freeze to death.

20 miles of ice cover is a lot of ice. You need a lot of energy to get through it. And the only energy you could extract would be by decomposing the water into hydrogen and oxygen and use a nuclear fussion reactor to get energy. But of course you do not usually carry one of those in your pocket, and you would need a lot of work to get the fussible fuel refined first.

Then there is the issue that what they could eat. Of course with energy and equipment (which they do not have) they could setup an hydroponics plant to grow the seeds/algaes that they (again) do not have, but that would take time to setup and to get results.

In short, your are setting a situation which requires lots of specialized equipment and preparation, and want to ignore that. Remember that technology is not magic(*): you require not only the knowledge but the basic techniques and the time and effort the develop the infrastructure.

To put an analogy, you could be the best Artic explorer in the world. But if you were suddenly teleported to the North Pole right now, you would die because you are not wearing right now the kind of equipment needed to survive there.

(*) Yes I do know that quote. OP's would be better served with magic, though.

Comment: I should have been more clearer, I will edit my question now

Comment: Yes please, **state what you want to ask in your question**. We are not able to read your mind so we can only answer to what you write. If your mind and fingers are disconnected, there is nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: That sweet suffering of a person not clarifying things in comment section, lol. In origin edit OP stated advanced tech, and clearly it needs to ask what it means, before to jump first in line to get free internet points. Depending on what that advanced tech means outcomes can be different. However not a bad answer to point some problems with OPs q.

Comment: Some problems, hm, I have to say it is flawed at its core as opinion based q, now instead to have no answers and vanish from wb, it will stick there forever, because u pinned it, or someone else with similar jump in attitudeds will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only energy that might be available on a rogue planet would geothermal energy due to active volcanism. Due to the limited resources your space travelers have, they don't have the means to access such energy.

If you want to want to have a stronger scientific basis for the story it might be better to shift the focus of the settlement to one of the [moons orbiting the rogue planet](https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2018-10-11/rogue-planets-moons-life-gas-giants-jupiter-solar-system/10334026).

Moons can have geothermal energy due to their own radioisotopes providing heat for geological activity and geothermal energy, but they can also generate heat via gravitational interaction with the planet they orbit due to tidal flexing.

> ... far from the warming rays of the sun, water stays liquid thanks to heat generated from friction, when a moon is warped by its planet's gravitational pull, as well as that of other moons.